# R: parse JSON/XML exported compound properties from Pubchem

Tags: json, xml, r, xml-parsing, pubchem

I would like to parse all chemical properties of a given compound as given in Pubchem in R, using the JSON (or XML) export facility.

Example: ALPHA-IONONE, pubchem compound ID 5282108

https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/5282108

```
library("rjson")
data <- rjson::fromJSON(file="https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug_view/data/compound/5282108/JSON/?response_type=display")
```

or

```
library("RJSONIO")
data <- RJSONIO::fromJSON("https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug_view/data/compound/5282108/JSON/?response_type=display")
```

will get me a tree of nested lists, but how do I go from this rather complicated list of nested lists to a nice dataframe or list of dataframes?

In this case, what I am after is everything under

3.1 Computed Descriptors

3.2 Other Identifiers

3.3 Synonyms

4.1 Computed Properties

in a single row of a dataframe and each element in a separate named column with multiple items per element (e.g. multiple synonyms) pasted together with a "|" as a delimiter. E.g. in this case something like

```
pubchemid      IUPAC_Name    InChI       InChI_Key     Canonical SMILES      Isomeric SMILES     CAS     EC Number     Wikipedia      MeSH Synonyms     Depositor-Supplied Synonyms   Molecular_Weight    Molecular_Formula    XLogP3   Hydrogen_Bond_Donor_Count ... 
5282108        (E)-4-(2,6,6-trimethylcyclohex-2-en-1-yl)but-3-en-2-one       InChI=1S/C13H20O/c1-10-6-5-9-13(3,4)12(10)8-7-11(2)14/h6-8,12H,5,9H2,1-4H3/b8-7+ ....
```

Fields with multiple items, such as Depositor-Supplied Synonyms could be pasted together with a "|", e.g. value could be ALPHA-IONONE|Iraldeine|...

Second, I would also like to import section
4.2.2 Kovats Retention Index
as a dataframe

```
pubchemid      column_class            kovats_ri
5282108        Standard non-polar      1413
5282108        Standard non-polar      1417
...
5282108        Semi-standard non-polar 1427
...
```

(section 4.3.1 GC-MS would have been nice too, but since it only displays the 3 top peaks this is a little useless right now, so I'll skip that)

Anybody any idea how to achieve this in an elegant way?

PS Note that not all these fields will necessarily exist for any given query.

2D structure and some properties can also be obtained from

https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/compound/cid/5282108/record/SDF/?record_type=2d&response_type=display

and 3D structure from

https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/compound/cid/5282108/record/SDF/?record_type=3d&response_type=display

Data can also be exported as XML, using

https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug_view/data/compound/5282108/XML/?response_type=display

if that would be any easier

Note: also tried with R package `rpubchem`, but that one only seems to import a small amount of the available info:

```
library("rpubchem")
get.cid(5282108)
CID  IUPACName CanonicalSmile MolecularFormula MolecularWeight TotalFormalCharge XLogP HydrogenBondDonorCount HydrogenBondAcceptorCount HeavyAtomCount    TPSA
2 5282108 (E)-4-(2,6,6-trimethylcyclohex-2-en-1-yl)but-3-en-2-one        C13H20O       192.297300               0                 3     0                      1                        14             17 5282108
```

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific on what "everything under" exactly means? Also, your explanation of expected data.frame is not very clear for me. Could you try and create by hand example (part of) row? I would also suggest to make "Kovats Retention Index" into it's own paragraph, since it doesn't seem to be hard requirement for you.

Comment: I made some clarifications - hope it's better now? With everything I basically mean any fields that are given for a given compound (this can vary from compound to compound)... So for multiple compounds the dataframes would still have to be merged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal works on XML files, because (thanks to XPath) I find them more convenient to traverse and select nodes.

Please note that this is neither fast (took few seconds while testing) nor optimal (I parse each file twice - once for names and the like and once for Kovats Retention Index). But I guess that you will want to parse some set of files once and go ahead with your real business, and premature optimization is the root of all evil.

I have put main tasks into separate functions. If you want to get data for one specific pubchem record, they are ready to use. But if you want to get data from few pubchem records at once, you can define vector of pointers to data and use examples at the bottom to merge results together. In my case, vector contains paths to files on my local disk. URLs are supported as well, although I would discourage them (remember that each site will be requested twice, and if there is greater number of records, you probably want to handle faulty network somehow).

Compound you have linked to has multiple entries on "EC Number". They do differ by `ReferenceNumber`, but not by `Name`. I wasn't sure why it is that way and what should I do with it (your sample output contains only one entry for EC Number), so I left this to R. R added suffixes to duplicated values and created `EC.Number.1`, `EC.Number.2` etc. These suffixes **do not** match with `ReferenceNumber` in file and probably the same column in master data frame will refer to different `ReferenceNumber`s for different compounds.

It seems that pubchem uses following format for tags `<type>Value[List]`. In few places I have hardcoded `StringValue`, but maybe some compound has different types in the same fields. I usually haven't considered lists, except where it was requested. So further modifications might be needed as more data is thrown at this code.

If you have any questions, please post them in comments. I am not sure whether I should explain that code or what.

```
library("xml2")
library("data.table")

compound.attributes <- function(file=NULL) {
  compound <- read_xml(file)
  ns <- xml_ns(compound)
  information <- xml_find_all(compound, paste0(
    "//d1:TOCHeading[text()='Computed Descriptors'",
    " or text()='Other Identifiers'",
    " or text()='Synonyms'",
    " or text()='Computed Properties']",
    "/following-sibling::d1:Section/d1:Information"
  ), ns)

  properties <- sapply(information, function(x) {
    name <- xml_text(xml_find_one(x, "./d1:Name", ns))
    value <- ifelse(length(xml_find_all(x, "./d1:StringValueList", ns)) > 0,
                    paste(sapply(
                      xml_find_all(x, "./d1:StringValueList", ns),
                      xml_text, trim=TRUE), sep="", collapse="|"),
                    xml_text(
                      xml_find_one(x, "./*[contains(name(),'Value')]", ns),
                      trim=TRUE)
    )
    names(value) <- name
    return(value)
  })
  rm(compound, information)
  properties <- as.list(properties)
  properties$pubchemid <- sub(".*/([0-9]+)/?.*", "\\1", file)
  return(data.frame(properties))
}

compound.retention.index <- function(file=NULL) {
  pubchemid <- sub(".*/([0-9]+)/?.*", "\\1", file)
  compound <- read_xml(file)
  ns <- xml_ns(compound)
  information <- xml_find_all(compound, paste0(
    "//d1:TOCHeading[text()='Kovats Retention Index']",
    "/following-sibling::d1:Information"
  ), ns)
  indexes <- lapply(information, function(x) {
    name <- xml_text(xml_find_one(x, "./d1:Name", ns))
    values <- as.numeric(sapply(
      xml_find_all(x, "./*[contains(name(), 'NumValue')]", ns), 
      xml_text))

    data.frame(pubchemid=pubchemid,
               column_class=name,
               kovats_ri=values)
  })

  return( do.call("rbind", indexes) )
}

compounds <- c("./5282108.xml", "./5282148.xml", "./91754124.xml")

cd <- rbindlist(
  lapply(compounds, compound.attributes),
  fill=TRUE
)

rti <- do.call("rbind",
               lapply(compounds, compound.retention.index))
```

Comment: Ha thanks a lot for this! That was exactly what I was looking for! Nice also that you used xml2 as with the XML package I also had problems with memory leaks!

Comment: @Mirosław Zalewski please have any idea how to retrieve ATC CODE for a give CID in pubchem using the same concept?

Comment: @aliocee please ask this as separate question. Comments are for corrections, clarifications and other short remarks. They are not for asking and answering questions similar to main question.

Comment: @MirosławZalewski question with regard to the question, some <information> tags have StringValue not StringValueList how can we extract those in 'properties' ?